How to protect github actions self-hosted runner?
The documentation of self-hosted runners states the following https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-for-github-actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#hardening-for-self-hosted-runners :

As a result, self-hosted runners should almost never be used for public repositories on GitHub, because any user can open pull requests against the repository and compromise the environment. Similarly, be cautious when using self-hosted runners on private or internal repositories, as anyone who can fork the repository and open a pull request (generally those with read access to the repository) are able to compromise the self-hosted runner environment, including gaining access to secrets and the GITHUB_TOKEN which, depending on its settings, can grant write access to the repository. Although workflows can control access to environment secrets by using environments and required reviews, these workflows are not run in an isolated environment and are still susceptible to the same risks when run on a self-hosted runner.

Is setting the following seting on github repository:

enough to protect self-hosted runners from unprivileged access to a public user repository? Should additional steps be taken?

Hi, to the downvoter - please tell me why.

By default any runner can access only to the current repo. Self-hosted runner acting the same. You can give it more permissions if you specify it directly in the code of your workflow. See here for more details.
Or by giving it a specially created token.
The main problem with such runners is that all the computer variables, its entire electronic signature, become available to the public. Of your repository is public.
The picture you provided is about a situation where someone forked your project, made changes to theirs fork, and is trying to contribute to your project. If you have workflows that trigger on a pull request, this option prevents any attacker from spamming your runners.

What is "electronic signature"? That's a new term.

Hi, thank you. any runner can access only to the current repo any runner can access the resources it is running on. The current repo is irrevelant, I want to protect the infrastructure the runner is running on.

If you have workflows that trigger on a pull request workflows are part of the repo. So it is irrelevant - the user can modify the workflow and execute them irrelevant of what "I" have in the master branch - it is important what "they" have in they pull request. I am not interested about "problems with such runners" - I understand them. Bottom line, what is the solution to the problem, except for not using self hosted runners. I want to restrict all workflows from anywhere that were not triggered by me, unconditionally. How do I achieve that?

Oh,not sure, but you can restrict workflows on the current repo and create new repo, add token with high permissions. Then, put your workflows to the new repo, restrict access to anybody, also you could use restriction to actor in the body of workflow.

There is a bit more to it than that. The UI you show is specifically for PRs on their repos getting access to your workflows, but they can just make a PR on your repo.

You can edit the workflow as part of the PR, and thus you can pretty much run any code you like.
Even if 1 is not a thing, usually you find some place in the build process where something is executed and replaces that in the PR.

So result is that all your build secrets is potentially exposed.
Furthermore, for self-hosted runners, an attacker may gain access to your compute, storage, internal networks and additional secrets and privileges you have given your runners.
TLDR: Don't let code run without review

Hi. Thank you. Don't let code run without review How do I do that? My question is about which steps should I take? If this setting is not enough, what setting should I use? Bottom line, I do not care about the reasons, I just want to know what to do so that not-reviewed code will not run on my runner. If other users can do some forks and some pull requests that can do something on my runner, how do I prevent it?

I dont think there is a way to have to approve each code change. Personally we setup our runners in k8s and configured network security so that it access nothing but public internet ips. Plus our runners have no special priviliges, so worst case someone commits some crypto shit and spends our compute. For priviliged stuff, we use workflow_dispatch to an internal repo workflow.

You can see how kubernetes-sigs handle it via labels here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/external-dns/actions/runs/11679653868/workflow?pr=4849 . They set always require approval, and then have script that gives that approval based on a label
